# Download image from a lot of pages that located on a one website

Tags: automation

I need to download image from a lot of pages that located on a one website.

More specific:
I get a list of url's from one website.
Image on every page have the same class name.
So I need to download this image from every page.

How to automate this work? Please, help me to create a script.
Thanks!

Comment: Automated to which degree? On which OS? Which language do you know? In which way is the list provided? What did you try? Where did you fail? Have you code to show?

Answer (score 0):

try with Wget : `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget`

You have to create a bash script on linux. Maybe search on google to find a script wich is already done.